# init.rc: invalid service name

Tags: android, service, init

Trying to start a service via init.rc on Android.

```
service name_of_my_service /path/to/my/service
    user root
```

Getting the following error:

> init: Invalid service name name_of_my_service

Answer (score 7):

Your service name is too long (or contains invalid characters).

Service names can be at most 16 characters long, and can contain alphanumeric characters, "_", and "-".

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-4.2.2_r1.2/init/init_parser.c#411

Comment: Thank you!! I spent a few days racking my brain trying to get my daemon to start.